# Using Array to fetch multiple URL via HTTPGET in java

Tags: java, arrays, http-get

I have a string array a[] that contains several urls that I want to pass into my HttpGet code below

```
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);{
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build()){
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(a[i]);

                /*WRITE TO FILE*/
                /*try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(a[i]))){
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if (entity != null) {
                        try (FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(AgentRequirements)) {
                        entity.writeTo(outstream);
                        }
                    }
                }*/

                /*SHOW EXECUTION*/
                System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
                try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                }
            }
    }
```

I have a failed build because it says that system cannot find symbol 'i'. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `;` at the end of the for loop, because if it stays there, then the forloop doesn't loop, because the block is already closed. That's why `i` cannot be found outside of the block (your try-catch).

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);{
    // your code
}
```

is the same as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){}
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here :

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);{
...
}
```

is first a loop with an empty statement

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);
```

followed by a block statement (that's as nothing to do with the loop)

```
{
...
}
```

The problem comes from your loop that iterate and do nothing, same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    ;
}
{
...
}
```

Just remove the `;` that divide the loop from the block of statemnt. That way, the block will be the one execute for each loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    ...
}
```

FYI :

It is important to know that nothing prevent you to add block statement anywhere in a method.

So you can have

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(i);
        {
            int j = 0;
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        System.out.println(j); // ERROR - j doesn't exist here
    }
    System.out.println(i); // ERROR - i doesn't exist here
}
```

The idea is that `i` only exist in that block, you can't use it outside of the block.

Comment: Your answer is nicer. It really explains the why and how. Also i like your information snippet at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);
                              ^
```

You have a loose semi colon that breaks your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your forloop is not well formated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);{
```

remove the semi colon ";"

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);
```

Redundant symbol ';' at the end.  It closes the 'for loop' operator